# Radiobutton-Buttons with pure html/css

Tags: jquery, html, css

is it possible to create radiobuttons like the [JQuery](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#radio) ones, with pure html/css?

thanks

Comment: i don't think so it is possible..

Comment: Hi KenavR, do you mean only styling the buttons, or functionality as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mcXm7/1/ 
this example is 100% pure CSS and it works fine on newer browser (of course feel free to add all necessary style to make buttons look like as in your example)

HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="rd" id="choice1" value="1">
<label for="choice1" >Choice 1</label>

<input type="radio" name="rd" id="choice2" value="2">
<label for="choice2" >Choice 2</label>

<input type="radio" name="rd" id="choice3" value="3">
<label for="choice3" >Choice 3</label>
```

CSS

```
label { display : inline-block;
        padding : 2px 5px;
        cursor  : pointer;
        border  : 1px #b6b6b6 outset; }

input[type="radio"] { 
        display: none; 
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label { 
        border: 1px #b6b6b6 inset; 
}

/* hover style */
input[type="radio"] + label:hover { ... }
input[type="radio"]:checked + label:hover { ... }
```

Unfortunately `:checked` isn't supported by `IE<9`: see http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-support-ie9/ for complete list of css/css3 features available so for older browser a javascript fallback is necessary to properly work.

a basic example of JS fallback: http://jsfiddle.net/mcXm7/2/ (no need to also load jQuery UI)

Comment: +1 nice ... would be even better if you posted the code within the answer too ...

Comment: I did not know this was possible... I runs terribly in Chrome though.

Comment: @Jivings Works fine for me ... in Fx *and* Chrome.

Comment: I just updated anyway with a simple example of javascript fallback for IE<9