# Making fancy radio button like pills

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, radio-button

I'm looking for a solution for replacing old fashioned radio buttons with something closer to the ["pills" as defined in Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navs) in a form.

I guess it's not possible to do this just by using CSS on Radio Button, but do you know if there's similar solution out there (with JQuery for instance)?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe this discussion about a pure css solution can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513272/radiobutton-buttons-with-pure-html-css/9513349#9513349

Comment: Check this out, might help you in future [CSS Deck](http://cssdeck.com/labs/fancy-radio-button)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here are two buttons project in github

http://hellohappy.org/css3-buttons/

http://nicolasgallagher.com/lab/css3-github-buttons/

Comment: Awesome! The "grouped button" was what I looked for. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is a bootstrap issue on github concerning exactly this:

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/1161

It contains several solutions including a CSS-only one: http://jsfiddle.net/charettes/SauLj/